# App converted to ARC, now getting warnings about my properties

Tags: ios, xcode, automatic-ref-counting, warnings

I just converted my app to `ARC`, and while it builds fine, I get like 600 warnings, all pertaining to my properties.  Such as:

> Default property attribute 'assign' not appropriate for non-gc object
>
> No 'assign', 'retain' or 'copy' attribute is specified - 'assign' is
>   assumed

[image: Screenshot for warning]

After Xcode converted my code, here is what my properties look like:

```
@property (nonatomic) EKEventStore *eventStore;
@property (nonatomic) EKCalendar *defaultCalendar;
@property (nonatomic) UIActionSheet *currentActionSheet;
@property (nonatomic) UILabel *noEventLabel;
```

Someone talked about needing to add `strong` to all of these.  Is this the case?  Did Xcode forget to add something?

Comment: What did the properties look like before conversion? Haven't used ARC yet, but I'd expect to see (nonatomic, retain) or  (nonatomic, assign) etc

Comment: Yes, before they were (nonatomic, retain)

Comment: may be you can see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25917861/why-obj-c-property-default-ownership-assign-instead-of-strong?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 21, accepted):

ARC is right. You cannot have *no* memory-management qualifer; you *must* say assign, retain (or strong which is the same thing), or weak.

Previously, assign was the default. But that is probably not what you want, because is it is the worst possible option - it is an old-style non-ARC weak reference. You either want a smart ARC weak reference (goes to nil when the object goes out of existence) or a strong reference (memory-managed for you by ARC).

Comment: Ok, since they used to be (nonatomic, retain) I assume I would now want (nonatomic, strong), is this correct? Why wouldn't Xcode have done this for me?!

Comment: Because whether or not a property is strong or weak is up to the developer. One of Apple's goals for ARC was for it to be 100% reliable, so they're not going to assume one way or the other (the assumption of assign was before ARC so that's different).

Comment: @NicHubbard: This actually does sound like a potential bug. If you had `retain` before, then presumably you want `strong`. You may want to [file a bug report](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: @matt: It's always been legal to just say `(nonatomic)` alone, but it also always issued this warning if you did so for obj-c objects.

Comment: ARC code assumes `strong` by default for properties (which equals `retain`). You only get this warning if the header is imported into a non-ARC Obj-C file since for non-ARC the default is `assign` (which equals `unsafe_unretained` in ARC). https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#property-declarations

Answer (score 8):

Sorry to add a second answer, but this turns out to be more intricate than I thought. It turns out that you're seeing a changed behavior (perhaps a bug?) in Xcode 4.3.

In Xcode 4.2, the converter would have offered to change `(nonatomic, retain)` to `(nonatomic, strong)`. But in Xcode 4.3, it offers to change it to `(nonatomic)`; I guess if you don't want that, changing `retain` to `strong` is up to you before converting.

On the other hand, in Xcode 4.2, `(nonatomic)` alone was absolutely illegal for a synthesized property; in Xcode 4.3, it is not: you get a warning, but it assumes you mean `assign` and so it isn't illegal.

So there's been a change in how ARC works in LLVM 3.1 and an accompanying change in the Xcode 4.3 ARC converter.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. The default now is STRONG, not assign. So (nonatomic) alone should mean (nonatomic, strong). The warning is the one that's wrong.

Comment: And this, ladies and gentlemen, is why the project I still can **NOT** successfully convert to ARC on my main, Xcode 4.2-machine, that I transferred via LAN to another Mac running Lion/Xcode 4.3 to migrate and then back, won't build. I think we can all agree that ARC is still in **beta**?

Comment: Let me see if I get this: So, If I manually search/replace all my `(nonatomic, retain)` to `(nonatomic, strong)` **before** migrating, the resulting code will compile in **both** Xcode 4.2 **and** 4.3?

Answer (score 4):

I think the answers are wrong.

In Xcode 4.3 you get a warning. However, it assumes you mean RETAIN. Retain is the new default for codes under ARC. Someone told me that xcode is fixing this.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: This is correct. More accurately, obj-c object properties are strong by default.