# Getting Rid False Warning After Upgrading to ARC

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.3

After I upgrade to ARC, I got a bunch of false warning

Those are:

**Assigning retained object to unsafe property; object will be released after assignment**

what happen is the object uses default property and as we know the default in ARC is retain

**No 'assign', 'retain', or 'copy' attribute is specified - 'assign' is assumed**

What happen is if there is no assign retain or copy default is retain

Looks like it's a bug in Xcode4.3 that simply hasn't taken into account the change.

I just want to get rid the warning so not to clutter my program how do I do so?

Comment: Just explicitly declare as strong with `__strong`

Comment: That is a good answer. I need better answer. Something that doesn't involve me changing hundreds line of code. Still if you make that into an answer and there is no other answer then it'll be the one that I select.

Comment: Similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608534/app-converted-to-arc-now-getting-warnings-about-my-properties

Comment: actually any way I can declare that as strong easily with say search and replace

Comment: On a related note I got this error when one of my configurations was set to have ARC OFF -- while others like Debug/Release had it ON. Automatic conversion didn't set it ON for all configs.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with LLVM 3.1 the ownership is implicitly `strong` (as documented in the [LLVM ARC documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ownership.spelling.property)). So with the next versions of Xcode, the error messages should disappear. I would add the `strong` modifiers for now (so that the properties don't get `assign` ownership), and delete them later when Xcode includes LLVM 3.1.